injecting javascript on samsung internet browser?
Is there any way to inject JS in websites on Samsung internet browser anymore? They patched bookmarklets a year ago as a "vulnerability" (So now you can't run javascript: bookmarks)
Extensions are propietary and you can't add third party ones it seems
I've tried looking to make either extensions, userscripts or others to inject JS on websites like custom playback speed script for YouTube. However it doesn't seem like I can inject JS in any way on Samsung Internet Browser

Mobile browsers are annoyingly difficult to customize. If there's a way, I suspect it requires jailbreaking.

When I've searched for ways to use extensions on mobile Chrome, all the solutions required switching to a different Chromium-based browser that enables this feature.

Any browser that can use TamperMonkey is all you need, it's what I use.
